# In IE11 background colors not working on printing

Tags: javascript, css, printing, internet-explorer-11

On IE11 background colors are not working on printing;
`case: style="background-color: rgb(xx, xx, xx);` - ignore on printing.
I tried:

```
color-adjust: exact;
```

but that is not working on IE (only FF)

Comment: well is the setting enabled to print background colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to check that IE background print feature is enable or not.

http://prntscr.com/gztny5

also include this css to webkit browser

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

Hope this is help you

Comment: -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; - didn't help me
How I can open this settings?

Comment: Can I do something else for that? (not change settings)

Comment: Go into Menu "File" and click on "Print page setup". In popup you can see this option

Answer (score 1):

You must turn on printing background colors to get any background-color attributes to print.

1. On the Tools menu -> Print -> Page Setup
2. Click to select the Print background colors and images check box, and then click OK.